# How to change CSS class in Python - flask website

Tags: python, css, flask

What is the simplest way to change class name form `.black` to `.white` in the example below using python and flask framework? For example: after mouse click on div `#area` ?

CSS file:

```
#area {position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;}
.black {background-color:#000;}
.white {background-color:#fff;}
```

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="area" class="black"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think ```.toggleClass()``` is the easiest way to go. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). If you use jquery then look [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: you have to use `JavaScript` for this - and it is not part of `Flask`

Comment: I remembered a not very popular method: you can write some code in `Python` and use [transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/examples) to convert it to `JavaScript` which can run in web browser. OR you can load JavaScript library [brython](https://brython.info/) which can run some Python code in browser. But usually people prefer to use directly JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This need `JavaScript` and it has nothing to do with `Flask`

Example using `querySelector()`

```html
<div id="area" class="black" onclick="change();"></div>

<script>
area = document.querySelector('#area');

function change(){
    area.classList.replace('black', 'white');
}
</script>
```

or using special variable `this`

```html
<div id="area" class="black" onclick="change(this);"></div>

<script>
function change(item){
    item.classList.replace('black', 'white');
}
</script>
```

---

Eventually you could use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`

```html
<div id="area" class="black"></div>

<script>
function change(){
    this.classList.replace('black', 'white');
}

area = document.querySelector('#area');
area.addEventListener('click', change);
</script>
```

or shorter

```html
<div id="area" class="black"></div>

<script>
area = document.querySelector('#area');
area.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.replace('black', 'white');
});
</script>
```

or even little shorter

```html
<div id="area" class="black"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#area').addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.replace('black', 'white');
});
</script>
```

---

Minimal working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>

<style>
#area1 {width:100px;height:100px;}
#area2 {width:100px;height:100px;}
#area3 {width:100px;height:100px;}
#area4 {width:100px;height:100px;}
.black {background-color:#000;}
.white {background-color:#fff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="area1" class="black" onclick="change1();"></div>
<br>
    <div id="area2" class="black" onclick="change2(this);"></div>
<br>
    <div id="area3" class="black"></div>
<br>
    <div id="area4" class="black"></div>

<script>
area1 = document.querySelector('#area1');

function change1(){
    area1.classList.replace('black', 'white');
    console.log('change1');
}

function change2(item){
    item.classList.replace('black', 'white');
    console.log('change2');
}

function change3(){
    this.classList.replace('black', 'white');
    console.log('change3');
}

area3 = document.querySelector('#area3');
area3.addEventListener('click', change3);

area4 = document.querySelector('#area4');
area4.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.replace('black', 'white');
    console.log('change4');
});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Python` you would have to use `<a></a>` which would send information to server when you click it. And server would use `Python` to generate HTML with new `class` and send it back to browser. But it means to reload all page and it needs time.

---

Minimal working code:

I put black `area` in `<a></a>` which `?color=white` and when server gets it then it sends back HTML with white `area` and with `?color=black`, etc.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    color = request.args.get('color', 'black')
    if color == 'black':
        other = 'white'
    else:    
        other = 'black'

    return render_template_string('''    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>

<style>
#area {width:100px;height:100px;}
.black {background-color:#000;}
.white {background-color:#fff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="/?color={{ other }}"><div id="area" class="{{ color }}"></div></a>
</body>

</html>''', color=color, other=other)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not popular but you can load `JavaScript` module [Brython](https://brython.info/static_tutorial/en/index.html) to run some Python code in web browser. But you can uses only modules converted to `JavaScript`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>

<style>
#area {width:100px;height:100px;}
.black {background-color:#000;}
.white {background-color:#fff;}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.9.1/brython.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="brython()">

    <div id="area" class="black"></div>

<script type="text/python">

from browser import document

def change(ev):
    if document['area'].attrs['class'] == 'black':
        document['area'].attrs['class'] = 'white'
    else:
        document['area'].attrs['class'] = 'black'

document["area"].bind("click", change)

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

There is also [transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/examples) which can convert some Python code to JavaScript code and run in web browser.

Similar module [RapydScript](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, but it must be Python. I have found solution for printing a list, for example:
If I create a list called `'content'=['white','black']` the code below will print: `white black` and it works fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>


    {% for x in content %}

      {{x}}

    {% endfor %}

  </body>
</html>
```

So according to my question the code below should also work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>

    {% if x==1 %}
        <div id="area" class="white"></div>
    {% else %}
        <div id="area" class="black"></div>
    {% endif %}

  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't, any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of x here? In your loop you assign x in the for loop based on content. If x exists, wouldn't the value be either white or black?

Comment: No, this is another example,you can assume that x is equal to 1. Anyway it doesnt matter, if x is equal to 'white' or 'black' the 'else' statment should work either.

Comment: if this is not solution for your problem then don't put it as asnwer but add it to question.

Comment: you can't change `class` on `click` using `Python` - Python generates this HTML before sending to browser but `click` works in browser. You would have to use `links`  which send information to server and it uses `Python` to generate new HTML and send new HTML to browser - but it meas reloading all HTML in browser - like loading new page.

Comment: code in `{%  %}` is part of template system `Jinja` and it is executed on server, not in browser, and it generates HTML which is send from server to browser.